# Prepend html before html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html template (jquery, js and everything is imported in the head). So here is this part, I try to prepend new paragraphs before the existing p with the id "board-page":

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p id="board-page">some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my javasript:

```
var boards = [];

function Board(title) {
    this.title = title;
}

function appendBoards() {
    for (var i in boards) {
        var board = boards[i];
        var title = board.title;
        $("#board-page").prepend("<p>"+title+"</p>");
    }
}

addNewBoardWithTitle("some other text");
addNewBoardWithTitle("other text");
appendBoards();
```

But this doesn't work, nothing happends. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Put more code, in your code snippet `boards` is an empty array so `prepend` would not be called and it means we can't check the data `appendBoards` is using is correct.

Comment: Post the code for `addNewBoardWithTitle` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insertBefore for this ..

```
var boards = [];

function Board(title) {
   this.title = title;
 }

function appendBoards() {
    for (var i in boards) {
       var board = boards[i];
      var title = board.title;
       $("<p>"+title+"</p>").insertBefore("#board-page");
   }
}

addNewBoardWithTitle("some other text");
addNewBoardWithTitle("other text");
appendBoards();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var boards = [];

function addBoard(title) {
    var obj = {}
  obj["title"] = title;
  boards.push(obj)
}

function appendBoards() {

  for (var i in boards) {
    var board = boards[i];
    var title = board.title;
    $("#board-page").prepend("<p>" + title + "</p>");
  }
}
addBoard("tes")
appendBoards()
```

And also try to not append/prepend in a loop rather collect it all in a string and do one prepend/append.
https://jsfiddle.net/rbpgva4c/